# Accessing server response

Tags: php, json

I have got a response from a server as follows :

```
object(Stripe\Account)[7]
  protected '_opts' => 
    object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)[6]
      public 'headers' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'apiKey' => string 'sk_test_abcdefghijklm' (length=32)
  protected '_values' => 
    array (size=26)
      'id' => string 'acct_abcdefghijklm' (length=21)
      'email' => null
      'statement_descriptor' => null
      'display_name' => null
      'timezone' => string 'Etc/UTC' (length=7)
      'details_submitted' => boolean false
      'charges_enabled' => boolean true
      'transfers_enabled' => boolean false
      'currencies_supported' => 
        array (size=138)
          0 => string 'usd' (length=3)
          1 => string 'aed' (length=3)
          2 => string 'afn' (length=3)
          3 => string 'all' (length=3)
          4 => string 'amd' (length=3)
          5 => string 'ang' (length=3)
          6 => string 'aoa' (length=3)
          7 => string 'ars' (length=3)
          8 => string 'aud' (length=3)
          9 => string 'awg' (length=3)
```

I have caught the response in a php variable $account. I want to get id from this response. ie. i want to get `'id' => string 'acct_12abceefghigk' (length=21).` I have searched stack overflow and tried following ways. But could not solve it. Can you please help ?

1.

```
 foreach($account->list as $a=>$b)
 {  
    foreach($b as $c=>$d)
    {   
       var_dump($c);
       var_dump($d);
    }

 } // This prints nothing.
```

2.

```
foreach($account->list as $a=>$b)
{
   var_dump($a);
}//This prints nothing.
```

Also can you please explain what (Stripe\Account)[7], protected '_opts' means ? I an new to php and do not know what to search into google for this.

Regards,
Tanvir

Comment: what does `var_dump($account->_values);` output? I usually do what you've done and then work my way down until I just have the value I want.

Comment: @RightClick it it giving null. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: what is the full output of `var_dump($account);` ?  Is that what you posted?

Comment: @RightClick. I have found the answer. $account->id gives it. Thanks for your help and support .  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend has found the answer. It seems very simple. $account->id gives the id.

But i do not understand how it works.

Thanks,
Tanvir